# Domains listed multiple times on new log out page

Tags: bug, status-completed, logout

When I load [`/users/logout`](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/logout) on any site, I see the following:

> [image: Log Out screen shot]

Really?  Clicking this button will log me out from not only stackoverflow.com, but also from stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com, as well as stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com, and stackoverflow.com, all with one click?  That's a pretty handy service!

It seems like it should list each domain only once.

I'm seeing this in Firefox 39.0, by the way.  (I don't know whether that's relevant or not.)

Comment: Hah. Well. That got reported earlier internally but in a much more... mild form. Hooboy.

Comment: Needless to say, it'll *also* log you out from stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Woof. This will be fixed in the next build. Thanks for the report!

I fixed the display issue, although unfortunately this turned up a bigger problem - we're creating extra session rows on login that should not be there. It doesn't seem to be causing *problems* per se, since I assume you are successfully logged in or else the report would be about that. :) Still, gonna need to dig into that one this afternoon.

P.S. The session generation bug has also been fixed.

Comment: And when is the build coming out? Because it will log me out of "Superuser Superuser Serverfault Serverfault"

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy The build is out now.